# Unit Testing WCF REST Services

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I've got a WCF REST Service which I'd like to unit test. i.e - I've got all the business logic tested (full separation of layers), but would like to check if the WCF service works as wanted with all the logic and the real DB.

I couldn't find any useful info on this.

Each method looks like this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Version?ts={ts}", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public WCF_Response GetVersion( string ts)
{
    return new ApiVersion { 
        version = VersionManager.CurrentVersion(),
    };
}
```

i.e - with an URI template. Otherwise it's a normal WCF service.

Before I write a web based unit testing, help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Waitin](http://watin.org/) can be used to test web applications- I assume that it could be leveraged for REST services as well.

Comment: Cool tool. will help not only in this project :)

Comment: Isn't `Waitin` for UI test automation? Question is rather on unit testing isn't it? PS: I'll take my comment back. My bad, I only read the title. Looks like roman wants an integration test after all. No offence  :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/wcf/index.html

I used it last year on a large WCF rest project and it worked great.

Don't have access to the codebase anymore but the unit tests also used castle windsor IoC, so I could run all tests with no external dependencies.

They looked something like

```
Component.For<IOrder>()
     .Named("order.service")
     .ImplementedBy<Order>()
    .ActAs(new RestServiceModel()
     {
      Endpoints = new IWcfEndpoint[] { WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WebHttpBinding() { TransferMode=TransferMode.Streamed, MaxBufferSize=int.MaxValue,MaxReceivedMessageSize=long.MaxValue }).At(OrderUrlBase) }
     })
```

Now the service is hosted by the unit test(not in IIS) and can be called using OrderUrlBase Url

Comment: Thanks. I feel this might be somehow an over kill... though not sure.

Comment: the wcf facility makes wcf much much much more palatable - both client and server